# PowerShell, RegEx: replace?

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to replace a number but it doesn't work?

```
    $l = "prg=PowerShell°V=2.0°dtd=20120602°user=kjuz°pwd=jhiuz°chk=876876"
    $nxtDate = 20140526
    $l -replace '°dtd=(d+)', '°dtd=$nxtDate'
```

This is what I get (no change still 2012)

```
    prg=PowerShell°V=2.0°dtd=20120602°user=kjuz°pwd=jhiuz°chk=876876
```

What do I wrong?
That's working:

```
    $l -replace '°dtd=(\d+)', "°dtd=$nxtDate"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a `\` next your `d+` expression like this:

```
°dtd=(\d+)
```

Comment: ah - yes, you are right - it's late, time to sleep :(